# kill autosys job using Talend

Tags: talend, autosys

i want to kill a autosys job using Talend tSystem component with 'sendevent' command.

the command is : sendevent -E KILLJOB -j 
but i got error : sendevent : command not found

any help on this..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information a)what Linux you are using b) how the tSystem content looks like c) if sendevent works if you call it on commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might find this [link](https://communities.ca.com/thread/241756507) useful